# How can I use workflow library in application using AndroidX?

Tags: android, androidx

I'm trying to create an application that uses workflow (Square's Android library)

I see on their Github project page that migration to AndroidX is currently blocked: https://github.com/square/workflow/issues/66

Does that mean that I can't use it in my application if I'm using AndroidX libraries?